# C# parsing "4.1" and "4.10" as "4.1". How to parse number as "4.10"?

Tags: c#, excel, parsing

I'm parsing an excel file in C#. I am organizing procedures with number identifiers (e.g. `4.1`, `4.2`, `4.3`, ... , `4.10`, `4.11`).  It all works except any number ending in `".10"` is parsed as `".1"`.  The value I am doing a `.ToString()` on is of type dynamic.

So I don't even have it as a `string` first.  How can I get `".10"` as `.10` (and not as `.1`)?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Math says that `4.1 == 4.10 == 4.100` ect; if you want to *represent* `double` value with `2` digits after decimal point use foramatting: `value.ToString("F2");`

Comment: *"How can I get .10 as .10?"* is not a clear question, since `.10` **is** `.10`. Please add some detail and code sample to your question.

Comment: @dmitry Actually that's not always what math says.

Comment: I think it's worth noting, that it is not uncommon to want to **display** the level of precision of a number, and that seems to be exactly the consideration to this question; but @coderiffic this is not a matter of parsing of a value, it is the display format of it. you do not **parse** `string` to `string`, you parse `string` to `double` and encode `double` to `string`. However, based on comments in your question, that doesn't necessarily reflect what you're actually doing.  Provide a code sample.

Comment: your comment, "I don't even have it as a `string` first", you aren't representing it that way to us, and the notion conflicts with your title and question.  If it isn't a string, then don't put double quotes around it and state you are parsing it.  If it is infact not a `string` in your excel sheet, then that needs to be clarified, and your question should be modified to remove confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Numerically, 4.1 = 4.10, so double.Parse() is not your friend here.

The problem is you aren't really parsing a *number*, you're parsing a *hierarchy* that uses dotted numbers at each level.

So, rather than parsing to a `double`, you're better off parsing to an *array of integers*. Something like this:

```
Array.ConvertAll("4.10".Split('.'), n => int.Parse(n));
```

This will allow you to handle any number of "levels" in the hierarchy, and any number of digit places at each level.

If you want to store the hierarchy in, say, a database column that will preserve the intended order, just emit the array as a *string*, with left-hand zeros padding each level to the number of digits you're comfortable with.

If you only have two levels, you can get away with storing your number as `decimal` type, but you'll still need to left-pad the numbers, i.e., store 4.1 as the number 4.001, 4.10 as 4.01, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that I bet you are wanting to a) parse the strings as is and b) then sort based on the value, where 4.9 comes before 4.10, and 4.11.  If you parse this to any single object value you won't get what you want.  You'll need to put this into a string, then convert it somehow.  The easiest way to do this is to split the string, and sort by the 1st number, then the second.

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on into *what type* do you parse the initial `string`.

In case of `double` or `float` e.g.

```
  double value = double.Parse("4.10", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

you *can't* obtain anything like `4.10d` since math stands that `4.1 == 4.10 == 4.100 == ...`; all you can do is to *represent* `double` as a `string` with a help of formatting:

```
  // represent value (4.1) with 2 digits after the decimal point: 4.10
  Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F2"));
```

In case of `decimal` (which has *scaing factor* so you can have `410` with scaling factor `2`: `410 / 10**2 == 4.10` or `41` with scaling factor `1`: `41 / 10**1 == 4.1`) you *can* obtain the desired value: you should add `0.00m` for this:

```
  decimal value = decimal.("4.1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 0.00m;

  // 4.10
  Console.WriteLine(value);
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 for details